# img nested inside anchor tag behaves differently

Tags: html, css, image, anchor

I have an image that is nested inside an anchor tag which is nested inside a div. The image has been given a width of 40px and a height of 40px.

When I look the image in the dev tools, it shows me that is has a width and height of 40px and behaves as intended.

[image]

But when I check the anchor tag in which the image is nested it shows me that it has a height of 15px.

How is that possible? Since the anchor tag is wrapped around the image and the image has a height and width of 40px shouldn't the anchor tag also have a height and width of 40px?

Why is the anchor tag showing under my image? Why is it not wrapping my image tag? What is this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the HTML fragment for clarity?  Include any CSS that affects it.

Answer (score 0):

The  element defaults to a display value of inline. Therefore it will resort to the default line-height of 18px. Yours shows 15px. Did you add some sort of padding or margin?